# XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of string-length()

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm getting this problem in the moment of XML Transform to Object using a XSLT template

> XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of string-length()

My Xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <NS1:Header>
      <NS2:metadata xmlns:NS2="http://www.test.net/services/metadata/v2.0">
         <serviceId>id</serviceId>
         <serviceVersion>1.0</serviceVersion>
         <locale>pt_BR</locale>
         <internals/>
      </NS2:metadata>
   </NS1:Header>
   <NS1:Body>
      <NS1:Fault>
         <NS1:Code>
            <soapenv:Value xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value>
            <NS1:Subcode>
               <NS1:Value>UNKNOWN_ERROR</NS1:Value>
            </NS1:Subcode>
         </NS1:Code>
         <NS1:Reason>
            <NS1:Text xml:lang="en">tranformData. tente novamente</NS1:Text>
         </NS1:Reason>
         <NS1:Detail>
            <NS3:errors xmlns:NS3="http://www.test.net/services/errors/v1.0">
               <error>
                  <code>UNKNOWN_ERROR</code>
                  <message>unknow error.</message>
                  <type>GENERIC</type>
                  <source>tranformData</source>
               </error>
               <error>
                <code>UNKNOWN_ERROR</code>
                  <message>unknow error.</message>
                  <type>GENERIC</type>
                  <source>tranformData</source>
               </error>
            </NS3:errors>
         </NS1:Detail>
     </NS1:Fault>
   </NS1:Body>
</NS1:Envelope>
```

My XSLT Line:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(//source/text()) + string-length(//code/text()) > 0">
```

Please Help-me.

Comment: What you posted as XML is not a valid XML. Without the full picture I think you probably select multiple `source` elements with `//`,

Comment: Add the complete XML. Thanks for response.

Comment: So now you can see that you have multiple source elements and with `//` you are selecting many. You can select first with `//source[1]` but I don't know what your expectation is when you have multiple.

Comment: If you tell us your goal, we might be able to suggest a better way.  For example, if you're trying to test for the presence of errors, you might just use `test="//error"`, which will return true if there is an `error` element anywhere in the response, or `test="//NS1:Fault"` if a `NS1:Fault` exists (assuming you've properly declared the `NS1` namespace prefix.

Comment: @kjhughes I need get the values inside the tag error. like this: <code>
       <xsl:value-of select="//code/text()" />
      </code> . Just the first. Only if the tag error show in the xml.

Comment: `//error[1]/code/text()` will select the text node child the `code` element child of the first `error` element in the response.  You might want to look up the notion of *string-value* of an XML element.